# Как парсить интернет приложение?

Tags: java, парсер

Вот сайт http://sd.366.ru/ .   Как такое парсить? Подскажите на чем это написано и в какую сторону смотреть. К тому же вход по логину.
Я так понимаю такая штука имеет собственное api , ответы на запросы и надо парсить, только как мне узнать какие запросы мне делать.

**UPD**
Следуя вашим подсказкам я пришел к тому, что используя Jsoup смог авторизоваться на http://my.id-soft.ru (это такой же софт работающий на сервере как и Интрасервис).

```
public static void main(String[] ars) throws IOException {

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36";

        // Получаю токен
        Connection.Response resp1 = Jsoup.connect("http://my.id-soft.ru/auth/login").method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
        String token = resp1.parse().getElementsByTag("input").first().val().trim();

        System.out.println(token);

        // Упаковываю все в пост и отправляю
        Connection.Response resp2 = Jsoup.connect("http://my.id-soft.ru/auth/login").referrer("http://my.id-soft.ru/auth/login").userAgent(userAgent)
                .data("_token", token, "login","Mylogin", "password", "qwerty").cookies(resp1.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST).timeout(10000).execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = resp2.cookies();
        Document doc = resp2.parse();
```

Теперь мне не ясно вот что: При каждом ли новом запросе я должен отправлять токен, пароль, логин? Или могу только куки дальше использовать. Или токен? Немного запутался в том как правильно строить следующий запрос. 
Но это ладно, основное что мне нужно это понять как в таких приложениях находящихся на стороне сервера нажимать на кнопки. Вот у меня имеются фильтр. Я хочу обновить с учетом нажатого фильтра. Включаю Fiddler жму кнопку фильтра и уже идет запрос.  Только ради того чтобы показать мне поле выбора фильтра. Ну ладно, оно подгружается. Запрос такой.

```
 POST http://my.id-soft.ru/tickets/getPopupFilterData HTTP/1.1
Host: my.id-soft.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Accept: */*
Origin: http://my.id-soft.ru
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://my.id-soft.ru/tickets
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlBIMFUxNG5NQVкукикуки

field=status
```

Как я вижу новое здесь только `field=status`

После того как я выбираю один из статусов вижу отправляется такой запрос:

```
POST http://my.id-soft.ru/tickets/popupFilterDo HTTP/1.1
Host: my.id-soft.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8
Accept: */*
Origin: http://my.id-soft.ru
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://my.id-soft.ru/tickets
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ill2WVRUbFVLd1lXeXpxQlVкукикуки

status=2
```

Новое тут только `status=2` 
 Ну и дальше после выбора фильтр сам срабатывает. Так вот вопрос, обязательно ли сперва мне надо сделать запрос с `field=status`  , а потом с  `status=2` или сразу последний запрос? Если бы это был сайт меня бы интересовал конечный результат, тут это может не прокатить. Конечно не проблема поэкспериментировать, но что-то у меня не получается в запрос добавить этот статус. Я бы приложил ответ парсера при авторизации, но он огромен. Хотя нужная часть может есть в этом

```
<ul class="tabs_content"> 
 <li name="tabs11" class="tabs_content_active"> 
  <div id="filterStatusContainer" style="display: none;"> 
   <input type="button" id="filterStatusCancel" value="" onClick="location.href='http://my.id-soft.ru/tickets/clearFilter'" style="margin-right: 5px;"> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="filterStatusCheckbox" onClick="changeFilterStatus($(this))" style="display: none;"> 
   <span> </span> 
   <input type="button" id="filterStatusProperties" value="Настроить" style="display: none;"> 
  </div> 
  <div id="scroll_table35" class="scrollTable" style="border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9; background-color: #fafafa;"> 
   <div class="content"> 
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sort_table_header"> 
     <tbody>
      <tr class="top_tr_border"> 
       <th name="col00" width="74">№<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterId" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col05" width="130">Приоритет<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="priority" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col02" width="126">Дата создания<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterDateCreate" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col04" width="586">Адрес размещения<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterLocName" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col03" width="98">Код 1С<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterLocId" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col02" width="600">Тема<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterSubjectName" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col03" width="150">Статус<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="status" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col04" width="300">Рабочая группа<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterWrkGrpName" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col04" width="200">Исполнитель<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="tableFilterSpecialist" value=""></th> 
       <th name="col06" width="130">Срок<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtnOrderDesc orderBtn" name="date_target" value=""></th> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody>
    </table> 
    <div id="scroll_table" class="scrollTable"> 
     <div class="content"> 
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="sort_table_body"> 
       <tbody>
        <tr class="" priority="5" name="946560" specialist="93791" status="2" subject="562" initiator="64507" location="4422" workgroup="82" onclick="get_ticket_data($(this));" ondblclick="get_ticket_data_dblclick($(this));">
```

Как видите есть такая строчка

```
<th name="col03" width="150">Статус<input type="button" class="tableFilterBtn" name="status" value=""></th>
```

В которую я никак не могу value="2" влепить. 
Ну вопросы в том как правильно выставлять фильтр и вообще нажимать на кнопки, достаточно ли отправить запрос или придется использовать Силениум (что такое не знаю, понял что помогает на кнопки нажимать). Ну и помогите выставить фильтр, если это возможно через запрос без всяких Силениум.

И кстати сам я пробовал добавить `data("status","2")` в запрос, но ответ не похож на реальный.

Comment: https://intraservice.ru/upload/iblock/006/0066cb25f282420c5730f1b972aba8ae.pdf

Comment: Крутооо)) но мне больше нужна общая инфа, есть еще вот такой софт http://my.id-soft.ru/ .

Comment: В следующий раз добавляйте данные для входа, мы же не можем просто так что-то посмотреть

Comment: но я ведь не могу тоже разглашать пароли компании

Comment: Alex Chermenin, как я понимаю  для my.id-soft.ru открытого апи нет. Можно ли как то самому узнать какие я запросы использую.

Comment: в google chrome открываете сайт. идете в меню->дополнительные инструменты->инструменты разработчика, открываете вкладку network, делаете что либо на сайте и смотрите какие запросы он отправляет и что получает в ответ

Comment: Я поставил Fiddler , но хрома достаточно, чтобы увидеть запрос. Проблема в том, что в запросе кроме логина и пароля отправляется токен, а откуда он берется не пойму.

Comment: мм.Вроде понял. Просто обращаюсь к странице и он мне дает токен. Только каждый раз токен разный. Я его сперва получаю, а потом добавляю в новый запрос, но он уже не валидный..

Comment: vladF, добавил всякую инфу, где есть на что посмотреть)) Буду рад если поможете с запросом